# Position absolute right: 0 doesn't place element correctly

Tags: css, sass, css-position

I want to adjust navigation to the right when not in mobile view and I want to do it with absolute positioning of `ul` element. I don't know why but it doesn't work. I know that it could be done with `float: right` but the reason for this question is to understand what's wrong with my understanding of how does CSS work. So [here's the code](https://codepen.io/avalan4e/pen/jYPmYg). I suppose @media query is the very part of our interest

Comment: How are we supposed to help you understand the issue you are having with CSS when you don't provide valid HTML and SCSS? Please provide a somewhat working example via codepen/jsfiddle and provide more detail on what it *should* look like. I cleaned up your invalid syntax, please start with something like this: https://codepen.io/bensewards/pen/mpJmPp

Comment: Easy man, I've got you. Working on codepen example at the moment. Thx for the advice.

Comment: @BenSewards is it OK for you know?

Comment: @BenSewards as far as I can see you've just moved the constants outside class selector and completely removed the interactive JS part. It would be very nice of you if you explain the reason. I've put constants inside class selector only for modularity purpose. I don't want them to appear anywhere but in this particular class.

Answer (score 1):

For your ul element, change css property left:0 to right:0

Comment: That was a moment of desperation and frustration. Sure thing you're right. I guess I just desired a break and that's how my unconscious mind reacted. But people are mean here, at least sometimes. Good luck!

Comment: Glad i was of some help